# What is the meaning of simply __ double underscore as a variable name？ Just __ not follow another chars

Tags: python, ipython, naming-conventions, built-in

When I run `ipython` on Windows 10 and execute `dir` function, got this:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: dir()
Out[1]:
['In',
 'Out',
 '_',
 '__',
 '___',
 '__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '_dh',
 '_i',
 '_i1',
 '_ih',
 '_ii',
 '_iii',
 '_oh',
 'exit',
 'get_ipython',
 'quit']

In [2]:
```

There is a `_`, `__` and a `___` above, what's the meaning of those variables as a built-in variable?

And also didn't get the meaning of `_i`, `_iii`, seems this thing only defined in `IPython`.

`_oh` shows a dict which stores all outputs on ipython.

Comment: They have no special meaning in Python, the ipython shell uses them for history

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I just found that they are define only in `IPython`. But why `IPython` do this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the IPython [docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system), the `_*` values cache the values of recent outputs:

> The following variables always exist:
>
> - `_` (a single underscore): stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
> - `__` (two underscores): next previous.
> - `___` (three underscores): next-next previous.

Conversely, the `_i*` variable [store recent inputs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#input-caching-system):

> `_i`, `_ii`, `_iii`: store previous, next previous and next-next previous inputs.

Answer (score 2):

_ is used for: 1. interpreter, 2. after name, 3. before name
f.e. for ignoring values:

```
# Ignore a value 
for _ in range(5) 
    print "Test"

# Ignore a value when unpacking 
a, b, _, _ = my_method(var1)
```